# Trouble with pyinstaller executable file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I've recently been trying to create an executable file for my code using pyinstaller for others to easily run. It took me a while to figure out how to even use pyinstaller correctly (kept running into various errors) and now I got it to run successfully but the resulting .exe file is blank and then crashes.

I was able to grab a screenshot of the errors before it crashed. Any ideas?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/psrln.png)